# Using preg_replace in PHP - Strange Behaviour

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following:

```
$string = '4745518 some text 4510018 some text 4743618 4745518 some text 4510518 some text';
$newstring = preg_replace('/[1-9]{7,7}/','NEWTRANSACTION: $0',$string);
```

My intent is "replace all occurrences of seven digits with 'NEWTRANSACTION: ' plus those seven digits."

However, my result is:

```
 NEWTRANS: 4745518 some text 4510018 some text NEWTRANS: 4743618 NEWTRANS: 4745518
 some text 4510518 some text
```

In other words, it appears that only some of the seven-digit groups are being replaced.  If I edit the original string, shift the seven digit groups around, those same seven digit groups get replaced.  It's like only certain combinations of numbers are being marked for replacement.  My actual input string is hundreds of lines long, and it really appears that random seven-digit groups are being replaced.

Can anyone see what's wrong?  Thanks in advance.

=== EDIT ===
Thanks for all of the help so quickly.  I would up using
`/\b\d{7}\b/`
and it works like a charm.  I'm new to regex, so I learned a bit here -- although not realizing the missing '0' was total boneheadedness on my part.

My bad, showing 'NEWTRANSACTION: ' in the code, but showing 'NEWTRAN:' in the output.  I was just typing the output, instead of copy/paste, and shortened it accidentally.

Thanks again.

Comment: `1-9` but some of your groups of digits have zeroes as well.

Comment: Why are you getting `NEWTRANS:` instead of `NEWTRANSACTION:`? Please show the output that actually comes from the code.

Comment: BTW, `{7,7}` can be written as just `{7}`. Also, this will match a number with more than 7 digits, because it just matches the first 7 digits in the number. If you want to be more restrictive, put a word boundary at the end: `[0-9]{7}\b`

Comment: Also note you can use `\d` in place of `[0-9]`.

Comment: @Barmar a boundary is necessary to limit the match on both sides, otherwise it would just match the last 7 digits, instead of the first. hence: `/\b[0-9]{7}\b/`

Comment: MichaelDee  did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code working fie after changing  `[1-9]` to `[0-9]` (As your digits have 0 also at some places)

```
<?php

$string = '4745518 some text 4510018 some text 4743618 4745518 some text 4510518 some text';
echo $newstring = preg_replace('/[0-9]{7,7}/','NEWTRANSACTION: $0',$string);
```

https://eval.in/984686

***Note:-*** A much shorter code given in a comment by @GrumpyCrouton,@kaii and @Barmar

```
/\b\d{7}\b/
```

Output:-https://eval.in/984792

Comment: For an even shorter pattern you could use `\d` in place of `[0-9]`. You could also replace `{7,7}` with `{7}`, and there should probably be a word boundry at the end `\b` - so the final shorter pattern would be `/\d{7}\b/`

Comment: As @Kali mentioned above, you should also have a boundary at the beginning: `\b\d{7}\b`.